# Excel VBA Identify highest number in object names

Tags: vba, excel

Im creating a form with a list of team members as checkboxes which will then run certain actions for each selected person. I have named the checkboxes CheckBox1-10. A loop is used within the code to loop through all the checkboxes:

```
For i = 1 To 10
    If Me.("CheckBox" & i.Value = True
        'Do whatever
```

If a new team member needs added to the form I have created instructions on what the naming format should be of the checkboxes however rather than have people going into the code and changing the for loop is there anyway I can determine via VBA the highest checkbox number so I can use this in my for loop rather than hardcode?

Obviously I know users could still make mistakes on the form - incorrectly naming the checkboxes, deleting members that no longer exist and thus deleting out a number in the loop but just trying to minimise their interaction to the code

Altering the answer provided below slightly so it did not apply to radio buttons this worked:

```
Dim cb As Variant
For Each cb In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(cb) = "CheckBox"
        'your code here
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can simply use:

```
YourWorksheet.Checkboxes.Count
```

Also, you can loop through all checkboxes with a for each statement:

```
For Each cb In Yourworksheet.Checkboxes
    'Your code here
Next
```

If you're in a user form, there is not CheckBox collection. However, you can loop through all checkboxes with this code:

```
Dim cb As Variant
For Each cb In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf cb Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
        'your code here
    End If
Next
```

Comment: there no way of using the numbers within the names? Im just thinking if they accidently create a CheckBox12 rather than CheckBox11. Count would still only see 11 wouldnt it and so CheckBox12 wouldnt be included in the loop or is that not how .count works?

Comment: ah that for each one might be what im after. Will this work for each checkbox in a form? the checkboxes are on a userform rather than the worksheet

Comment: Working great, only thing is.. its seeing my 2 radio buttons as checkboxes and entering the loop? Not sure why as when I use the immediate window at runtime to show what type the radio button it shows the following: ?typename(obtnaccrued): OptionButton I could just say and <> obtnaccrued but any ideas why its doing this?

Comment: Slightly altered what you gave me so it didnt apply to the radio buttons: For Each cb In Me.Controls
            If TypeName(cb) = "CheckBox"             End If
        Next